# R help converting char to POSIXlt

Tags: r, datetime, time, strptime, posixlt

I am having a lot of problems converting a `char` data.frame into a `POSIXlt`. This is my `str` output:

```
'data.frame':   5846 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ date   : Factor w/ 184 levels "1/1/2015","1/10/2015",..: 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 ...
 $ time   : Factor w/ 680 levels "1:00:00","1:01:00",..: 63 72 72 73 73 75 75 75 76 76 ...
 $ morning: Factor w/ 2 levels "AM","PM": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ sender : Factor w/ 2 levels "Judith:","Saul": 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ iso    : chr  "1/8/2014 10:10:00 PM" "1/8/2014 10:19:00 PM" "1/8/2014 10:19:00 PM" "1/8/2014 10:20:00 PM" ..
```

I want to convert "iso" into `POSIXlt` using

```
dat$iso <- strptime(dat$iso, "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

But I get `NA` as a result.

Comment: I am not getting error using `v1 <- '1/8/2014 10:20:00 PM';
strptime(v1, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
#[1] "2014-08-01 22:20:00 EDT"`  Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: this value does not work for strptime("1/23/2014 11:27:00 PM" ,"%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

Comment: Just swap the %d and %m and it will work. `strptime("1/23/2014 11:27:00 PM" ,"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")#
[1] "2014-01-23 23:27:00 EST"`  My example was based on the assumption that %d is first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a similar output when doing

```
> iso = "1/8/2014 10:19:00 PM"
> strptime(iso,"%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
[1] NA
```

This is due to my default locale (fr_FR) that does not support %p. Changing this locale to "C", solves the problem:

```
> Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_TIME","C")
> strptime(iso,"%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
[1] "2014-08-01 22:19:00 CEST"
```

Comment: Thank  you very much, it helped but I still get a bunch of N/A   
 [93] "2014-12-01 19:05:00 EST"  NA                        NA                        NA

Comment: which strings yields NA ? are they similar to those that are working ?

Comment: month and day were switch that's why it was given me NA for month values higher than 12... thank you